# Replace structured table name with cell reference?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-365

Is there a way to take a formula...
tbl_hours[@**SUN**] and replace the SUN with the contents from another cell?

The user would would type a day of the week SUN, MON, TUE (or a cell would contain the current day of the week

Then, in a column in the table, a formula would change based on the day of the week.

Comment: Look into INDIRECT()

Comment: Thank you Scott. I had thought I read somewhere to avoid INDIRECT with structured tables...but that might have been for older versions of Excel.

Comment: I answered with the easiest most broad responce I could as your question does not give enough specifics to truly formulate an answer.  Yes one should avoid indirect, if possible, but with out more info(test data and expected output and the full formula you are currently using) that is all I can give.  Most likely it could be done with INDEX/MATCH instead.

Comment: @ScottCraner; Thank you, I will look into INDIRECT(). I have not been able to find another way. I appreciate your reply.

Comment: More specifically... I have a =NOW() field where I will pull the weekday out of. MON TUE WED. This would be in, say $A$1 called v_DOW. I would like to put that value into a formula within a table... Something like '=IFERROR(IF(AND(VALUE(LEFT([@SAT],FIND(" ",[@SAT])-1))<=v_FakeHour,VALUE(RIGHT([@SAT],FIND(" ",[@SAT])-1))>=v_FakeHour),"Open","Closed"),"CLOSED ALL DAY")
  Is this a good use case for INDIRECT?

Comment: Thank you, Scott! Your help along with HackSlash has solved my problem! I am very thankful. 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would first need a cell that is set up with a data validation list that holds the table column names.

EXAMPLE:

```
=INDIRECT("tbl_hours[" & J1 & "]")
```

In this example the data validation list is in cell "J1".

Comment: Yes. This works! Thank you so much. I am new to this forum. What do I do once the question has been answered? I really appreciate your help! 